# Assignment of delegate gets released against will

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, delegates, uitextfield

I am trying to implement an easy way to format `UITextField` as a currency field with a certain `UIKeyboardType` and a certain format. For the format, I'm assigning a delegate and letting that handle it.

My .h-file contains:`@interface UITextField (Currency)` ... `@interface CurrencyTextFieldDelegate <UITextFieldDelegate>`, and my .m-file is printed below.

I want to be able to do a `UITextField *textField = [...]; [textField formatAsCurrency];`. The number pad is shown correctly, but the shouldChangeCharactersInRange is never called.

My guess is that the delegate gets released as soon as formatAsCurrency is executed? I don't know. Any thoughts?

```
#import "CurrencyTextFieldDelegate.h"

@implementation UITextField (Currency)

- (void)formatAsCurrency {
    CurrencyTextFieldDelegate *delegateViewController = [[CurrencyTextFieldDelegate alloc] init];
    self.delegate = delegateViewController;
    self.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
}

@end

@implementation CurrencyTextFieldDelegate

@synthesize storedAmount = _storedAmount;

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSLog(@"shouldChangeCharactersInRange");
    // magic happens
    return NO;
}

@end
```

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're trying to do. The delegate is usually the controller whose view the text field appears in. You can't have properties (with a backing ivar) in a category, so I don't think there's a way to have a strong pointer to the delegate in the category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to make it easy to create several fields to be interpreted in the same way, on different ViewControllers. I extended `UITextField` with a `parseCurrencyField`-method, that set the keyboard to numpad, some other stuff and most importantly set the delegate.

My issue with this question was how to make the delegate stay alive, and my solution was simply to define it in my AppDelegate.

Now I can, on any `UITextField` wherever in my App, do a `[textField parseCurrencyTextField]`, and it will... be parsed as a currency field :)

Simple as that.